# Graphviz: Independent tree branch

Tags: binary-tree, graphviz

I did this on GVEdit. I want to know if it's possible to make every branch independent? Which means every answer in a independent case.

Take this for example:

```
digraph G{
 "Is it red" -> "no answer"[label="yes"]
 "Is it red" -> "Is it sweet?"[label="no"]
 "Is it sweet?" -> "apple"[label="yes"]     
 "Is it sweet?" -> "no answer"[label="no"]  
}
```

Print:

[image]

And I expected to print:
[image]

Last question, I tried to save my tree as png file on GVEdit, but don't know how to do it. My cmd is not working cause it cannot find dot file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different id's for the nodes having the same labels should do the trick:

```
digraph G{
 na1[label="no answer"];
 "Is it red" -> na1[label="yes"]
 "Is it red" -> "Is it sweet?"[label="no"]
 "Is it sweet?" -> "apple"[label="yes"]     
 na2[label="no answer"];
 "Is it sweet?" -> na2[label="no"]  
}
```

Comment: It works! Do you know how to save the png file by using the section above like "file, edit, window, graph and help"? Thank you!

Comment: Oh I figure it out! no worries :)